# Using abs() in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, absolute-value

I am trying to create a list of integers and then scan it in order to find the minimum absolute value of the substractions of the elements of the list. I have created the list, but there is problem in the code which finds the minimum absolute value, as the result it shows is not correct. I think it is probably in the possitions of the elements of the list during the loops. Can you help me find it?

For example, when I create a list `Α = [2, 7, 5, 9, 3, 1, 2]`, the result of `min` should be 0, but it is 1.

Here is my code:

```
min=1000
for i in range (1, N-1):
    for j in range (i+1, N):
        if (abs (A [i-1] - A [j-1])<min):
            min = abs (A [i-1] - A [j-1])
print ("%d" %min)
```

Comment: Python indexing starts from `0`. `range(1, N - 1)` starts from `1`.

Comment: The minimum *difference* is 0 in this case, because `2-2 == 0`.

Comment: do you want to scan\consider all possible subtractions?

Comment: How does N relate to the length of your list (A)? I'm guessing that you may be excluding a check of the last element, where `2-2` would be 0, because `range(x,y)` excludes y.

Comment: @CongMa: that is not an error in Mike's code. He uses `A[i-1]` and so starting at 0 would throw an error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're never reaching the last element, debug your code to see what's going on.

Comment: The answers so far are offering alternative approaches but not explaining the problem with the OP's code.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes, exactly.

Comment: @AndyG N is the number of elements of the list which is given by the user. There at the for loop I wrote range(1, N+1) and I placed each element at A[i-1].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be subtracting 1 from j in the inner loop as you end up skipping the comparison of the last `2`. It is better to make the adjustments in the loop ranges, rather than subtracting 1 (or not) in the loop code:

```
A = [2, 7, 5, 9, 3, 1, 2]

N = 7

mint = 1000

for i in range (0, N-1):
    for j in range (i+1, N):
        if (abs(A[i] - A[j]) < mint):
            mint = abs(A[i] - A[j])
            print(i, j)
            print(mint)
print(mint) # 0
```

I have also avoided the use of a built-in function name `min`.

---

To avoid the arbitrary, magic, number 1000, you can perform an initial check against `None`:

```
A = [2, 7, 5, 9, 3, 1, 2]

N = 7

mint = None

for i in range (0, N-1):
    for j in range (i+1, N):
        if mint is None:
            mint = abs(A[i] - A[j])
        elif (abs(A[i] - A[j]) < mint):
            mint = abs(A[i] - A[j])
            print(i, j)
            print(mint)
print(mint) # 0
```

Comment: This does not compare `A[-2]` with `A[-1]`. You should loop `for i in range(0, N-1)` and use `A[i]` instead of `A[i-1]`, too.

Comment: What if every difference is larger than 1000?

Comment: Thank you @tobias_k, I have corrected that. It also is a lot clearer, and easier to follow, if the range(s) specy what we will be comparing.

Comment: @Piinthesky Start the min at 10,000 ;) or start it as `None` and perform an initial check.

Comment: Start with the difference of the first two elements?

Comment: I've added an approach to my answer if we wish to avoid a magic number.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
A = [2, 7, 5, 9, 3, 1, 2]

temp = sorted(A)
min_diff = min([abs(i - j) for i, j in zip(temp [:-1], temp [1:])])

print(min_diff)  # -> 0
```

Sorting makes sure that the element pair `(i, j)` which produce the overall smallest difference would be a pair of consecutive elements. That makes the 
number of checks you have to perform much less than the brute force approach of **all** possible combinations.

---

Something a bit more clever that short-circuits:

```
A = [2, 7, 5, 9, 3, 1, 2]


def find_min_diff(my_list):
    if len(set(my_list)) != len(my_list):  # See note 1
        return 0
    else:
        temp = sorted(my_list)
        my_min = float('inf')
        for i, j in zip(temp [:-1], temp [1:]):
            diff = abs(i - j)
            if diff < my_min:
                my_min = diff
        return my_min

print(find_min_diff(A))  # -> 0
```

## Notes:

1: Converting to set removes the duplicates so if the corresponding set has less elements than the original list it means that there is at least one duplicate value. But that necessarily means that the min absolute difference is 0 and we do not have to look any further.

I would be willing to bet that this is the fastest approach for all lists that would return 0.

Comment: Sorting itself incurs a number of checks ;)

Comment: @AndyG True but I would argue it is faster.

Comment: "As a result, you can traverse the list just once instead of twice." I find this a bit misleading, though, as this does not reduces the complexity from O(2n) to O(n), but from O(n²/2) to O(nlogn+n)

Comment: @tobias_k I was in the process of updating that part; you are totally right.

Comment: Sorting is good, numpy is better: Ev. Kounis: 131 µs, Espoir: 75 µs, jp_data: 71 ms, quamrana: 225 ms (A an array of 1000 random integers) - Oh, just noticed, that the numpy solution now also uses pre-sorting. So sorting was the major advance here.

Comment: It is. The second version clocks in at 26 µs (the same array as before)

Comment: Oh, wait. This is not a fair comparison, since you shortcut 0 and an array with 1000 random integers between zero and 100000 rarely has only unique elements.

Comment: @Piinthesky And why is that not fair? Short-circuiting is not a privileged I enjoy alone.

Comment: Let's summarise: Your solution is better on average and for shorter lists (probably numpy overhead). Numpy is better for longer lists and no repetitions.

Answer (score 3):

This is a brute-force solution:

```
from itertools import combinations

A = [2, 7, 5, 9, 3, 1, 2]

min(abs(i-j) for i, j in combinations(A, 2))  # 0
```

Answer (score 3):

using numpy

```
import numpy as np
A = [2, 7, 5, 9, 3, 1, 2]
v = np.abs(np.diff(np.sort(np.array(A))))
np.min(v)
```

out : 0

Or You can use numpy only for the diff  part like this :

```
v = min(abs(np.diff(sorted(A))))
```

Comment: What is `t` here? This only works if you sort the input beforehand, see Ev. Kounis' answer.

Comment: In order your code to work you should sort list first, otherwise it will produce incorrect result. So it should be min(abs(np.diff(sorted(t))))

Comment: Shorter, using `np` only for the `diff` part: `min(abs(np.diff(sorted(A))))`

Comment: it's also possible , want to propose a  full numpy solution

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for:

```
A = [2, 7, 5, 9, 3, 1, 2]

diffs = []
for index1, i in enumerate(A):
     for index2, j in enumerate(A):
         if index1 != index2:
             diffs.append(abs(i-j))             

print(min(diffs))
```

Output:

```
0
```

**Updated** to exclude subtraction of same items

Comment: That would subtract each element from itself, so the answer would always be zero.

Comment: Ok, but the OP didn't mention that.

Comment: I suppose you could add an inner condition `i != j`

Comment: @AndyG, but that would exclude the two different `2`s from the data the OP supplied.

Comment: Yes, I meant to refer to the indexes, which you've adjusted your code to include.

Comment: @quamrana OP didn't have to mention that since we are talking about absolute differences and if something like that was allowed you could simply return 0 without checking anything.